# How to encrypt/decrypt a string in SuiteScript 2.0?

Tags: oracle, encryption, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

In SuiteScript 1.0, we can use `nlapiEncrypt/nlapiDecrypt` api functions to encrypt/decrypt strings. However, there is no direct translation of these two api functions in SuiteScript 2.0 according to 2.0 api documentation. The doc also points to the `crypto` module (which is mainly about creating `cipher/decipher` objects), but I don't really understand how this module can do the task. Can anyone please shed some light on this function? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you working with a cypher, hash, or encoding?

Comment: I am trying to rewrite a SuiteScript 1.0 script into a 2.0 one. The original script in 1.0 uses nlapiEncrypt/nlapiDecrypt to encrypt/decrypt IDs. I am not sure how to use relevant 2.0 functions to achieve the same effect as those functions do in 1.0.

Comment: SuiteScript 1.0 documentation does not mention nlapiDecrypt, but the nlapiEncrypt(s, algorithm, key) can "encode, obfuscate or encrypt" depending on the algorithm you used. So, what algorithm were you using (sha1, aes, base64, xor)?

Comment: Thanks! It seems that 1.0 API really does not have nlapidecrypt. The original script I have has it, so I guess it is an error on their end. Nevertheless, I hope to use AES. Also, is there any way to decrypt an encrypted ID using SuiteScript 2.0?

Comment: can you share some of your original nlapiDecrypt code? (without any sensitive data obviously)

Comment: The code I have right now is something along the line like: decryptedId = nlapiDecrypt(Id, ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM, ENCRYPTION_KEY); with algorithm and key being defined constants elsewhere. It has a very similar structure as the nlapiencrypt function. Also, what should I do if I wanna encrypt using AES? Thanks!

Comment: encrypting with SuiteScript 2.0 is clunky. You have to get a GUID from a Suitelet script. Use the GUID to make a secretKey. Use the secretKey to create a Cypher. Update the Cypher with you data to encrypt. Finalize the Cypher to extract encrypted text and iv. Got all that? Are you open to an external library?

Comment: Ahhh I see. That's roughly what I am trying to do now (except for the suitelet part as now I hardcoding a GUID in). For the external library part, I am open to anything as long as it works (though hopefully as simple as possible).

Comment: As of decryption, I guess it follows a similar process, use GUID to create a secret key, use the key and iv to create a decypher, update with the encrypted string, then final to out the decrypted string? (In this case, for each ID to decrypt, we need to pass its encrypted string, iv, and GUID to the decryption function? ) Anyway, thank you so much for the follow-ups!

Comment: https://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at it. Also, maybe you can move these into your answer below so that I can confirm and upvote your answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The crypto module offers AES Encryption/Decryption. To Encrypt:

   1. Obtain a GUID by creating a Suitelet with a SecretKeyField. After
      entering your key and submitting the form, the Suitelet will return a GUID. You will need this GUID for Decryption as well.
   2. Use the GUID to make a secretKey.
   3. Use the secretKey to create a Cypher.
   4. Update the Cypher with you data to encrypt.
   5. Finalize the Cypher to extract encrypted text and iv.
2. The crypto module offers the following algorithms for hashing:

   - SHA1
   - SHA256
   - SHA512
   - MD5

     You can hash with (HMAC only) or without a key.
3. The encode module offers the following encodings:

   - UTF_8
   - BASE_16
   - BASE_32
   - BASE_64
   - BASE_64_URL_SAFE
   - HEX

     You must specify the encoding you are coming from and going to

Alternately, you can use a [Library](https://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/) to do the same things much more simply.

Comment: Btw, I found this answer from the official support page with a sample code detailing the process: https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/49119 Just FYI for those viewing this answer later.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer not to use NetSuite's decrypt functionality since it makes use of a guid field that has to be generated using their `addSecretKeyField`. Additionally, they require another secret key as well as an initialization vector.

I could not understand what the purpose of their secret key was vs the normal one and do not want to be forced to use the guid/IV.

Taking the advice of Nathan Sutherland in his answer, I've found that the library [crypto-js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) works with netsuite (even server side).

## How to:

- Download [crypto-js v3.1.9-1](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/releases/tag/3.1.9-1) (apparently the later versions are incompatible with NetSuite).
- Put the file `crypto-js.js` somewhere under your SuiteScripts folder.

  - I chose a folder called `lib`

## Sample v2 NetSuite code

```js
define(['./lib/crypto-js.js', 'N/log'],
function (crypto, log) {
  // ...
  var encrypted = crypto.AES.encrypt('Message', 'My Passphrase').toString();
  var decrypted = crypto.AES.decrypt(encrypted, 'My Passphrase').toString(crypto.enc.Utf8);
  log.debug('encrypted', encrypted);
  log.debug('decrypted', decrypted);
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Jared Beach. I also experienced a similar issue trying to use CryptoJS and I solved it by uploading crypto-js v3.1.9-1 to Netsuite SuiteScripts folder, as you suggested.